# Rails: Set config.time_zone to the server's time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

For compatibility reasons I need to store and display all dates in the server's local time zone. To do this I configured the rails application like this in `application.rb`:

```
# Do not convert database DATETIME / DATE columns to UTC:
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

It works okay when I store dates they are stored in the server's local timezone. However when retrieving the data Rails converts it to UTC, so for example `Post.find(1).posted` returns `2016-02-02 18:06:48 UTC` but it is actually stored as `2016-02-02 13:06:48` in the database.

How can I keep Rails from converting it to UTC?

I thought that setting the application time zone to the server's local time zone will help so I wanted to set `config.time_zone` to the server's local time zone and tried with:

```
config.time_zone = Time.now.zone
```

But the problem with it is that it returns a three character timezone code like `COT` and config.time_zone is expecting a Time Zone name like `Bogota`

How can I translate the three character code to the full time zone name? or, how can I get the local time zone name? or, how can I configure Rails to not convert the database dates to UTC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just enter "Bogota" as the string for `config.time_zone` and with `config.active_record.default_timezone` set to `:local` you should get what you need. DB in local timezone (which, I hope, is Bogata's TZ) and the model attributes in Bogata's TZ too.

#### Update

Based on a comment, the OP wants to be able to set the timezone in Ubuntu at an OS level and then use that setting to configure Rails without any additional step.

So @Sergio, the good news is that you **can** set `config.time_zone` to [the IANA timezone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that you'd be familiar with in using the Ubuntu tools, ie. you **can** do:

```
config.time_zone = "America/Bogota"
```

So all you need to do is work out how to get that from your OS, I *think* it should be the contents of `/etc/timezone` so:

```
config.time_zone = File.read("/etc/timezone").chomp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what I have right now, however I want rails to take the Time Zone of the server where the application is running instead of having a fixed timezone.

Comment: A server doesn't know where it's located, you have to set that yourself by setting the `config.time_zone` setting (that's why Rails doesn't just do this for you).

Comment: Is true that a server doesn't know where it is located but you can actually configure a time zone for your server if you have root access, in ubuntu for example you can do `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and pick a time zone. This is the time zone I'm interested in. However if there is no way for rails to grab it I guess I'll just have to stick with a fixed one. Maybe I can put the time zone in the ENV.

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I wanted.

Comment: This is what worked for me: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo(File.read("/etc/timezone").chomp). That will get an actual timezone class object which is more useful than just a string.

Answer (score 1):

What about `Time.zone.tzinfo.identifier`, for me that's "America/New_York". I use it on Postgres, but I suspect that would give you the string you expect.

Comment: It cannot be used in `application.rb`: undefined method `tzinfo' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar for testing. Some of our tests relied on the days selected in a browser calendar, but late at night the server browser and the Rails backend were on different days due to time zone settings.

I ended up using the following:

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
...

config.time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[Time.now.strftime('%z').gsub('0', '').to_i]

...
```

This grabs the offset of the server time zone as an integer number of hours and calculates the configured time zone based on that. **This has limited usefulness, as there are multiple time zones per offset**. But as I only needed the times to match for testing, it was adequate for my use case.

It would be more helpful if the time zone could be derived from the server time zone short code (`Time.now.strftime('%Z')`), but I didn't find a solution for that.

Comment: `config.time_zone` from `application.rb` cannot read the time zone code :/